# Editar Archivos .docx y xslx desde Express y React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Tengo una aplicación web, la cual utiliza unos archivos de excel y de word para generar una documentación, estos archivos se encuentran guardados en un servidor local, el cual se encuentra en todas los equipos de la red como una carpeta compartida, al momento de desplegar la aplicación de forma local todo funciona correctamente, pero cuando la desplego en un servidor en la nube deja de funcionar, el servidor me responde que no encuentra los archivos de excel y de word, según yo, es por que esta buscando los archivos en el mismo servidor en la nube y no en la carpeta compartida que es donde están guardados.

¿Tienen alguna idea de como pueda solucionar esto?

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
const controlador = {};

controlador.Add = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

        wb.xlsx.readFile(req.body.BD)
            .then(() => {
                const ws = wb.getWorksheet(req.body.SheetName);
                ws.addRow(req.body.datos);
                wb.xlsx.writeFile(req.body.BD).then(() => {
                    res.status(200).json({ Message: "Guardado exitoso" });
                });
            });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ Message: "Ocurrio un error", error });
    };
};

controlador.Edit = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
        wb.xlsx.readFile(req.body.BD)
            .then(() => {
                const ws = wb.getWorksheet(req.body.SheetName);
                ws.eachRow((data) => {
                    for (let j = 0; j < req.body.datos.length; j++) {
                        if (data.getCell(1).value === req.body.datos[j][0]) {
                            for (let i = 2; i <= data.cellCount; i++) {
                                data.getCell(i).value = req.body.datos[j][i - 1];
                            };
                        };
                    };
                });

                wb.xlsx.writeFile(req.body.BD);
                res.status(200).json({ Message: "Guardado exitoso" });
            });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ Message: "Ocurrio un error", error });
    };

};

controlador.GetAll = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const wb = xlsx.readFile(req.body.BD, { cellDates: true, sheetRows: false });
        const ws = wb.Sheets[req.body.SheetName];
        const data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);

        res.status(200).json({ data });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ Message: "Ocurrio un error", error });
    };
};

module.exports = controlador;
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Suena a problema de permisos. Cuando dices que corre en la nube, qué significa exactamente? Localmente hay una unidad lógica del SO que mapea un recurso de red; en la instancia cloud es igual? Además, la instancia cloud debe tener permisos de acceso igual que tu servidor local (que posiblemente está conectado con tu usuario de la empresa, etc). Puedes validar manualmente en la instancia cloud que puedas ver esa unidad de red con el usuario que corre el servicio de tu aplicación?

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante, aclaraciones y respuestas a comentarios, a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta)

Comment: Ejecuto el servidor en heroku y la idea es subirlo en firebase functions, y cuando voy a guardar información en el archivo excel busca el archivo en el servidor directamente y no en el equipo local y ahí es cuando arroja el error.